# How to set the cursor pointer to center of `feedback` widget of `Draggable` widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, widget, draggable

My widget which is used as `feedback` value for `Draggable`widget may have variable width because of included text length. Any ideas how to set the mouse pointer to center of `feedback` widget in any case?